# wpf xaml Button with image, change color on mouse over how to respond to triggers?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

In wpf, xaml, I have been trying to figure out how to highligth an image and button when mouse is over. and I am having some trouble

Its a combination of a navigation bar, with text and images.

[image]

this is how it should look.

dark backgrounds, that changes color when mouse is over.
I am using devexpress, an have tried differnt ways to make it work...

a) grid solution
a grid, with an image and an simple text button after. with the sizes fixed...

- but that runs into the button changes color, when mouse is over, but not the image..
- (and if I (or user) click on the image no command is called on the the viewmodel.

---

```
 <Grid.Resources>
     <Style x:Key="navigationButtons" TargetType="StackPanel">
         <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="#000000"/>
             </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Grid.Resources>

   <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"  Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image  Source="..png" OpacityMask="White" Width="24" Height="24" Margin="32 20 16 20"/>
        <dx:SimpleButton />
    </StackPanel>
```

---

[image]

b) a stackpanel with stackpanels of images and texts..

- a the stackpanel, could probably be triggerd both by the mouse over, and by the user clicking.
- but the button would need to be styled not to show any affect on mouse over, since the panels
  should be styled to handle that

c) a stackpanel with buttons that contains image and text..

- the button doesn't look good, since the image and text are hard to place in the rigth positions.

---

```
<dx:SimpleButton Grid.Row="7" Width="328" Height="64">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="72"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="../Properties/Images/Home.png" OpacityMask="White"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{x:Static res:Resource.Home}" />
    </Grid>
 </dx:SimpleButton>
```

---

[image]

This doesn't really solve my problem either...
does any one have clue? - send me in the right direction. I've been looking at styles, and think those have a solution somewhere..

Thanks a bunch guru's.

Comment: Be aware that `OpacityMask="White"` or any other SolidColorBrush makes no sense at all. See [Opacity Masks Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/opacity-masks-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for how it is actually supposed to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code

```
<dx:SimpleButton Grid.Row="7" Width="328" Height="64">
   <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"  Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image  Source="../Properties/Images/Home.png" OpacityMask="White" Width="24" Height="24"/>
        <Label Content="{x:Static res:Resource.Home}" />
    </StackPanel>
</dx:SimpleButton>
```

If you do not get the desired result from the above code, use the following code. `Containers` do not have a `mouseover` trigger and you should use `eventtrigger` instead.

```
<dx:SimpleButton Grid.Row="7" Width="328" Height="64">
 <Grid>
     <Grid.Style>
          <Style TargetType="Grid">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.200" From="Transparent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" To="#FF11FF22" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.200" From="#FF11FF22" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" To="Transparent" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image  Source="../Properties/Images/Home.png" OpacityMask="White" Width="24" Height="24"/>
            <Label Content="{x:Static res:Resource.Home}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</dx:SimpleButton>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your problem is when you got hover by mouse its default color makes it unreadable. you can do something like this

```
    <Button Content="Button">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/> 
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

You have to set the *Setter Property background and Foreground color* that suits your design.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I have updated my comment for this solution.